# Type mismatch in expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to execute following query and it doesn't work.

```
SELECT
      ManageStudents.StudentId,
      ManageStudents.StudentName,
      ManageStudents.SubCharges,
      ManageStudents.StartSub,
      ManageStudents.EndSub,
      ManageStudents.IssuedBook,
      ManageStudents.DateOfIssue,
      ManageStudents.DateOfReturn,
      ManageBooks.BookName,
      ManageBooks.BookId
FROM
     ( ManageStudents
INNER JOIN 
      ManageBooks 
ON    ManageStudents.IssuedBook = ManageBooks.BookId)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

#### EDIT 1:

```
FROM  
     (ManageStudents 
INNER JOIN 
      ManageBooks 
ON 
      Cint(ManageStudents.IssuedBook) = ManageBooks.BookId)
```

`Cint()` worked sa expected. Thank a lot!  Problem has been solved!

Comment: What are the data types for `ManageStudents.IssuedBook` and `ManageBooks.BookId`?  They must be compatible if you want to join on them.

Comment: one of them is Int and other is Text

Comment: It shouldn't be that! Value of `ManageStudents.IssuedBook` must be equal to `ManageBooks.BookId`. Example: I got the book with id 233 (IssuedBook) and the book id (BookId) should also be 233. Otherwise how are you going to compare data?

Answer (score 3):

Use `CInt()` for the text field to cast it as integer.  Then Access will allow you to join that transformed field with an integer field.

If `IssuedBook` is the text field ...

```
ON CInt(ManageStudents.IssuedBook) = ManageBooks.BookId
```

If you're doing this in the Access query designer, it may complain it can't display the join in Design View.  However, you can switch to SQL View, modify the query, and execute it from there.  The SQL can still work even when it can't be displayed in Design View.

This task will be more complicated if the text field contains values which are not suitable for `CInt()`.  If that happens, please show us a sample of the problem text field values.

Answer (score 2):

There's only one place it can be;

```
ON ManageStudents.IssuedBook = ManageBooks.BookId
```

Make sure both of those fields have compatible data types.

Comment: one of them is Int and other is Text

Comment: Then replace the line I mentioned above with "On CInt(ManageStudents.IssuedBook) = ManageBooks.BookId" and that will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT
      ManageStudents.StudentId,
      ManageStudents.StudentName,
      ManageStudents.SubCharges,
      ManageStudents.StartSub,
      ManageStudents.EndSub,
      ManageStudents.IssuedBook,
      ManageStudents.DateOfIssue,
      ManageStudents.DateOfReturn,
      ManageBooks.BookName,
      ManageBooks.BookId
FROM
      ManageStudents AS ManageStudents
LEFT JOIN 
      ManageBooks AS ManageBooks 
ON 
      ManageStudents.IssuedBook = ManageBooks.BookId
```

I suppose that you have forgotten about `ManageBooks.BookId` on your `SELECT` in you initial example.

Comment: Thanks! Yes. I realized that later. Could you please edit his question as there is something really wrong with formatting! I believe he used your correct answer in his question by editing it. It's disruptive!